# Bootstrap responsive fixed width col that is always centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make a login page that has a fixed width   while having column  in the center of the page. Something like page :

```
https://www.amazon.com/sign-in
```

I have tried useing offset colms like this

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style=" float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Its not consistent  size this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a fixed-width DIV, you don't need Bootstrap's Grid. You just do:

```
<div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with Bootstrap's components since Bootstrap's columns are designed to use percentages for widths. So they will change size depending on the viewport size. You have to write some custom css code to do this.

You can use the following snippet to do what you want. It uses CSS media queries (which is what Bootstrap uses). I set the div to a width of `600px`. When you resize the window to less than `768px` it will change to `100%` width. I picked `768px` since that is the breakpoint for `xs` in Bootstrap.

```css
.col-fixed {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-fixed {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-fixed">
  This is a fixed width column that becomes 100% when viewport is less than 768px
</div>
```